# Rails Nested Forms and Model Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, nested, nested-forms, polymorphic-associations

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to understand if it is possible to use nested model forms (as in Railscasts #196-197) and model inheritance together.

I'm developing an app to create questionnaire similar to [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/newform?usp=apps_start&hl=en).

I have the model Questionnaire with the title and a set of Questions. 
So Question is a nested model of Questionnaire (to have the possibility to add and remove question while creating the questionnaire).

But as in Google Form there are several types of question depending on the several type of answer (text field, checkbox, radiobox and so on). 
So I was thinking to create several models for the questions (Question_text, Question_checkbox, ...) all subclasses of Question. But I'm not sure this is the correct way to handle this situation and how to implement it.

Comment: This must not be the correct way. You handle the types of question inside the `Question` model.

Comment: do you know a better way to handle it? thanks